# SQLAlchemy, threads, and table not such table errors

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlalchemy

I have a object that wraps all access to SQLAlchemy, let's called it Wrapper.  I use `sqlalchemy.orm.scoped_session` so that any session is local to the thread this class is in as per the documentation.  Now, I have a Master thread that creates an instance of Wrapper.  A few Slave threads are created by the Mater and passed a reference to the Wrapper.

When any Slave calls any SQLAlchemy called from within the Wrapper class, the following error is raised:

```
DB Exception raied: DB Error: (OperationalError) no such table:[...]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Should I create new instances of Wrapper for each Slave?

**Edit**: I am using a SQLite in memory database (mainly for testing) if that makes any difference.  And the winner is: *sqlite in memory cannot be shared between threads* so I can pass an engine to the Wrapper as long as it is not an in memory one.  Setting True to the verbose option is a very good debugging tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, either create a Wrapper in each thread, or have the Wrapper maintain a  pool of sessions.

Comment: Thanks.  What do I need to pass to the Wrapper?  I tried just the engine but that still gives me the error.

Comment: Pass the connection URI, ie "sqlite:///:memory:" or whatever, then create the engine/session in the Wrapper (if you want to have one per thread). EDIT: hm come to think of it, not sure it'd work with the sqlite memory db

Comment: If I do that, I get the error because I just create another instance of the sqlite:///:memory within the Slave thread.  If I pass it a real database (aka sqlite:///ook.db) then I can pass it fine.  BTW, like the avatar ^_~ GitS:SAC is very good indeed.

Comment: Yes, was just editing my reply as you've posted :). In case of a memory db, you might have to forgo a scoped_session and just use a regular session, implementing the thread safety (i.e locking) yourself

Comment: At this point, I may as well have a on file system database.  If it is  a testing run (say /var/tmp/test.db), I may as well delete it once I am done. Many thanks indeed.